# Can anyone one help with this noise is my car done please tell me?

Tags: engine, chevrolet, aveo

[image: car making noise here can I post the video it’s sounds like a clicking noise when pressing gas too !]
This car just started making this noise just gas pump replaced

Here it is

https://youtu.be/gbSFTtNxSJE

Comment: Please include a verbal description of the sound, a description of the conditions under which the sound appears, and a statement of the year and model of the vehicle.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! So I can better understand, the noise wasn't there prior to the fuel pump replacement? Also, have you checked the oil to ensure it is up to level?

Comment: Just check no oil I’m puzzled put three quartz the noise is almost completely gone I’m puzzled and no the noise wasn’t there prior to the gas pump being changed I’m confused

Comment: By "no oil" did you mean none at all? Or just low? Three quarts doesn't sound like a full load for most engines.

Comment: Well I can’t tell if there was none I put three quartz in and it stop making the noise